# conflict between tikz (was: todonotes) - tabularx - array - arydshln

Tags: tikz-pgf, tabularx, arrays, todonotes, arydshln

There is a conflict between the four packages tikz, tabularx, array and arydshln. The MWE below compiles, if I do not

- load tikz ( tikz.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151))
- (load todonotes (todonotes.sty    2018/11/22) calls tikz)
- use tabularx (usepackage and environment, tabularx.sty    2016/02/03 v2.11b)
- load array (array.sty    2018/11/13 v2.4j)
- load arydshln (arydshln.sty    2018/09/26 v1.74)

As @daleif noted, tikz called by todonotes is part of the problem.

Using all, I get:

> ! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
>   \@endpbox ...th \dp \@arstrutbox \fi \par \egroup 
>                                                     \adl@colhtdp \box \adl@box...
>   l.22   \end{tabularx}

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
% \usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{l l l }
        A & B & C
  \end{tabular}

  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l X X}
        A & B & C
  \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

How can I use all four packages without conflict?

Comment: it is not `todonotes` as is, you get the same error if you replace it with `tikz` (`todonotes` is build on tikz).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to an internal change in `array` we may try to adjust so the error goes away but in the mean time if you change the package order it works again

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{l l l }
        A & B & C
  \end{tabular}

  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l X X}
        A & B & C
  \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works for my MWE, but not if I change the tabular argument to {l : l l }

Comment: @ebcontrol, oops I'll raise this with the team...  (I'll post a temporary workaround here in a bit)

Comment: A Japanese LaTeX user also reported a similar issue: https://oku.edu.mie-u.ac.jp/tex/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=2550 - here I answered a workaround to revert array.sty's `\@startpbox` (removing `\color@begingroup`). Should i contact the author of arydshln (Mr. Nakashima), or expect the LaTeX team will resolve it?

Comment: Of course this issue can be minimalized to \usepackage{color} + \usepackage{array} + \usepackage{arydshln}. (Note: arydshln-man.pdf says arydshln should be loaded *after* array.)

Comment: @davidcarlisle It seems that arydshln.sty modifies `\@endpbox` based on previous version of array.sty, but it does not modify `\@startpbox`. For this reason, the update of array.sty made two macros incosistent.

Comment: @Hironobu YAMASHITA, this resolved my issues!
Using:
    \usepackage{arydshln}
    \usepackage{array}
    \makeatletter
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \patchcmd{\@startpbox}{\color@begingroup}{}{}{}
    \makeatother
I can compile both the MWE and my not so minimal document

Comment: @HironobuYAMASHITA please could you contact the author, as Frank notes here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/466261/1090  the extra colour group was added to array to fix a definite colour-leak bug in that code so unfortunately that requires some updates in higher level packages if they assume a specific group structure.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle OK, I'll contact the author Nakashima-san.

Comment: @HironobuYAMASHITA thanks, sorry we should have caught this earlier and given advance warning, but it's hard to check every package for every change...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I sent an e-mail to Nakashima-san. (Cc'ed to public list on Japanese Community: https://ml.texjp.org/pipermail/issue/2018-December/000203.html )

Comment: Nakashima-san sent me a candidate of new arydshln.sty and works fine ;-)

Comment: The fixed version of arydshln.sty v1.75 is out; available from CTAN.

Comment: @HironobuYAMASHITA Could you inform the author that there is a similar problem with longtable (the newest version from the tools update a few days ago)? A simple example is here https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48413939#48413939. It breaks with `! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Already done yesterday; https://ml.texjp.org/pipermail/issue/2019-January/000208.html and the author replied that he will look into it ;-)

Comment: @HironobuYAMASHITA thank you (I found today the message, and even if I can't read it I could see that it is about the problem.)

Comment: @HironobuYAMASHITA I apologise we didn't get more advance notice of this to package authors, just unfortunate timing that the original bug report on array came close to the latex release, it was a clear bug  (color leaked from a table cell, and easy to fix by adding "color groups") but we should perhaps have deferred it to give more time to contact package authors.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle arydshln v1.76 arrived on CTAN and TL: https://tug.org/svn/texlive?view=revision&revision=50084 it seems that the author fixed the conflict with longtable.