# Tabu very recently stopped working with color/xcolor or with fancyvrb

Tags: color, tabu, colortbl

Below is a MWE with a `tabu` table that compiled perfectly fine up until I updated packages today (Dec. 16, 2018) with TeX Live Utility.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabu}

\title{Example}
\author{Andrew Turner}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering

    \tabulinesep = 3pt

    \begin{tabu} spread 0pt {X[c$$]X[c$$]} \hline
        a & b \\ \hline
    \end{tabu}

    \caption{test}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

After the update, trying to compile gives a whole bunch of errors like this:

```
! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.19 \end{tabu}

I'm guessing that you meant to end an alignment here.

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.19 \end{tabu}

I can't figure out why you would want to use a tab mark
or \cr or \span just now. If something like a right brace
up above has ended a previous alignment prematurely,
you're probably due for more error messages, and you
might try typing `S' now just to see what is salvageable.
```

If I comment out the `xcolor` package, this fixes the issue, or if I get rid of the `spread 0pt` and keep the `xcolor` package this also fixes the issue. I looked at what just updated in TeX Live Utility, and I wonder if it has to do with the recent update of `colortbl`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

Here is a further example. This is actually exact same, as recent version(s) of `fancyvrb` require package `xcolor`.

> this is obsolete since release `3.2` (`2019/01/08`) of `fancyvrb` which does not load `xcolor` anymore.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabu}spread 0pt {XX}
A
&
B
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

breaks with

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.10 \end{tabu}

?
```

Simply commenting out loading of `fancyvrb` it compiles, or using TL2017 (my TL2018 is already fully updated...) it compiles also.

Comment: your log shows that it doesn't load colortbl, but it does load array so probably it needs a similar update to the update that colortbl needed....

Comment: So the update to `array` that required an update to be made to `colortbl` possibly requires a similar change to be made to the `tabu` package? Thanks for your help.

Comment: you should consider that `tabu` is not maintained, consequently changes in packages (for example in the `array` package), on which it is based, can be in conflict with it.

Comment: @jfbu I haven't had time to check yet but I assume it is `% \changes{v2.4i}{2018/09/13}{Add group to prevent color leak (gh/72)}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks I had missed that changes entry as I looked only at top of `array.dtx` file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## UPDATE 2019-01-14

An equivalent patch has been applied in tabu 2.9 which has been submitted to ctan.

---

This is due to fixing a color leak in p-columns in array which is used underneath tabu, longtable tabularx etc. The tabu package overwrites a number of array internals assuming an internal structure (and grouping levels) which doesn't any any longer exist the moment a color package is loaded.

After staring at the tabu code for a while I think (but I'm not yet sure) that it only needs adding `\color@begingroup` in one place.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\tabu@startpboxmeasure
  {\aftergroup\tabu@endpboxmeasure}
  {\aftergroup\tabu@endpboxmeasure
   \color@begingroup
  }{\typeout{tabu patched}}{\typeout{tabu patch failed!}}

\patchcmd\tabu@LT@startpbox
  {\bgroup}{\bgroup\color@begingroup}
  {\typeout{tabu patched}}{\typeout{tabu patch failed!}} 
\makeatletter
```

This does fix the sample document above and the tests that I made so far. If others could check with their documents I would appreciate that. Of course in the end that or something else would then need to go into the tabu code.

#### Update

Added a second patch in above needed to account for the same change made to longtable. Thanks to Ulrike Fischer for providing it (in a different question).

Comment: Just for the link: The answer by Ulrike that contains the second patch is probably https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/468958/35864

Comment: @moewe that's the one

Comment: I posted the following comment with an answer from Ulrike Fischer as well (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/468948/longtabu-and-color-compatibility/468958#468958): Is there a way to run this example with an older version of LaTeX as well (e.g. This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6840 64-bit))? At the moment it crashes with the mentioned version with a "! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.

Comment: @albert with an older LaTeX you should have an older array.sty for which the above patch is not correct (but issue should not be there either so no patch is needed). Note that the TeX version is irrelveant it is the LaTeX version that matters. Anyhow it is not impossible that there are issue with tabu in the earlier versions as well -- it is essentially unmaintained since 2011, so if you have problems they may be well unrelated. We are currently setting up an emergency fix for tabu covering those issue we know about, but we will not going to maintain the package. That should hit CTAN soon.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach The problem I would have had is that the generated LaTeX code should work with newest version (so with the latex3/latex2e patch) as well as with older versions. Seen the fact that the fixed tabu package (thanks!) will be on CTAN and in the distributions the latex3/latex2e and tabu are "inline" so no need anymore for local fixes.

Comment: @albert in a case like that you can try to wrap a patch into \@ifpackagelater so that it is only applied on defined circumstances. Not great but ...

Comment: @FrankMittelbach thanks, that was also one of the suggestions in the comments of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470107/incompatibility-of-fix-in-latex3-latex2e-in-respect-to-unmaintained-tabu-packa

Comment: The patch helped, thank you for posting. However, the updated tabu package is still not available.

Comment: @Oleksandr not sure where you looked, it is on CTAN: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabu and it also has made it at least into TeXLive afaik

Comment: @Frank, yes, when i checked two days ago in MikTeX Console, it did not show new version of tabu. Now, it is ok.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach Thank you very much for this patch. This originally worked for me, but now that the new tabu-fixed version has been released, the original MWE from my post above has errors again, with or without the patch you provided here. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @AndrewPatrickTurner you might try the new (though not yet final) patched version at https://github.com/tabu-fixed/tabu

Comment: For me, it is still broken, by the way, in one of the documents. the only difference with working documents is that i use following inline math formulas inside table cells: $\begin{aligned} \notag. 
                      \aligntab\begin{cases}
                       0, if a \leq 10 \\
                       \frac{b}{c}, otherwise
                      \end{cases} \notag
                     \end{aligned}$. PS. aligntab is defined as  \newcommand{\aligntab}{&}.

Comment: i found out that it is combo of cases and \frac, that is still causing the issue. once i remove any of them, it works.