# Incompatibility between tabu/floatrow and array.sty[2018/11/13 v2.4j]?

Tags: tabu

I just upgraded my texlive and can no longer use `tabu spread` when `floatrow` is loaded.

It seems that `array.sty` might be the problem as this is the only package to change recently.
I tried downgrading `array.sty` from [2018/11/13 v2.4j] to [2018/04/30 v2.4h], the MWE compiled without problems.

I am working on a template, so I have no control over package version.

Can anyone suggest a workaround?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{tabu}
\listfiles
\begin{document}

\begin{tabu} spread 0pt {|X|}
  anything \\
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

It yields:

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
                }
l.9   \end{tabu}
```

File versions in use:

```
 article.cls    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
floatrow.sty    2008/08/02 v0.3b floatrow: float package extension
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
caption3.sty    2018/09/12 v1.8c caption3 kernel (AR)
    tabu.sty    2011/02/26 v2.8 - flexible LaTeX tabulars (FC)
   array.sty    2018/11/13 v2.4j Tabular extension package (FMi)
varwidth.sty    2009/03/30 ver 0.92;  Variable-width minipages
   color.sty    2016/07/10 v1.1e Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
   xetex.def    2017/06/24 v5.0h Graphics/color driver for xetex
```

Comment: Use the patch from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/466261/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer the patch works. Really appreciate for your quick answer.