# longtabu and color compatibility

Tags: color, longtable, tabu, longtabu, latextools

After last update of TeX Live packages this code won't compile:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable,tabu}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {llX}
    a & b & c\\
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

I got an error:

> Missing } inserted. \end{longtabu}

if I comment out `\usepackage{color}` everything works.
Another strange thing - if I change last column type from `X` to say `l` - it also works (even with `color` package added).

Comment: I can reproduce the issue and guess it has to do with recent changes to `array.sty`, I suspect this is related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/466147/35864

Comment: It seems so. But workaround proposed here (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/466261/87293) doesn't work in my situation.

Comment: Also, it seems my issue is result of 2019-01-05 la­tex-tools update where issue mentioned by you was fixed.

Comment: The source of the problem is a small change in longtable.

Comment: The fix appears to be incomplete — see https://github.com/tabu-fixed/tabu/issues/1 — but I’ve just submitted a patch that *may* help us further along, __hopefully__ not breaking anything in the progress ☺

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## UPDATE 2019-01-14

An equivalent patch has been applied in tabu 2.9 which has been submitted to ctan.

---

The following seems to work (I also added the other patch):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\tabu@startpboxmeasure
  {\aftergroup\tabu@endpboxmeasure}
  {\aftergroup\tabu@endpboxmeasure
   \color@begingroup
  }{\typeout{tabu patched}}{\typeout{tabu patch failed!}}
  
\patchcmd\tabu@LT@startpbox
 {\bgroup}{\bgroup\color@begingroup}
 {\typeout{tabu patched}}{\typeout{tabu patch failed!}}  
\makeatletter

\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {llX}
    a & b & c\\
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to run this example with an older version of LaTeX as well (e.g. This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6840 64-bit))? At the moment it crashes with the mentioned version with a "! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup."

Comment: @albert did you ever figure out a way to add this patch only when needed?

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin No I didn't try as I want to try to stick to official distributions regarding LaTeX. I think this problem should be tackled on github in github.com/tabu-fixed/tabu and afterwards in CTAN distributions.

Answer (score 2):

The new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) is an alternative to the outdated `tabu` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\DefTblrTemplate{firsthead}{default}{}

\begin{longtblr}{width=\linewidth,colspec={llX},hlines,row{odd}={blue8},row{even}={azure8}}
 a & b & c \\
 d & e & f \\
 g & h & i \\
 j & k & l \\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]