# tabu: Error since update

Tags: tabu

Since the last update of tabu.sty I get the following error:

```
! Improper \prevdepth. \tabu@verticalspacing ... tempdimc \t
```

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}  
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\begin{varwidth}{0.91\linewidth}}l<{\end{varwidth}}}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tabu}{Lcc}
$\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\2\\3    
\end{pmatrix}$& 2& 3\\
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

The error occurs, when including pmatrix (or array) in a tabu-environment with a predefined column (using varwidth) AND strangely when including any other of a list of packages (like: color.sty, xcolor.sty, pstricks-add.sty, colortbl.sty, ...) Everything worked fine before the update!

Does anyone know, how to fix this?

Here is the first line of the `log` file:

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6930
>   64-bit) (preloaded format=latex 2019.1.13) 20 JAN 2019 12:55 entering
>   extended mode

Comment: Might be related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470107/incompatibility-of-fix-in-latex3-latex2e-in-respect-to-unmaintained-tabu-packa , probably some other / more problems here.

Comment: It's best to raise at https://github.com/tabu-fixed/tabu/issues but anyway clear test file, and I can confirm it fails, I'll see what I can do... (tabu internals are not well documented and the original author is out of contact)

Comment: This should be fixed in [tabu 2.10](https://github.com/tabu-fixed/tabu/releases)

Comment: With TeX Live 2019, the latest update for tabu is only 2.9. Do I have to wait until TeX Live 2020 to get tabu 2.10, or is there another way?

Answer (score 15):

I think this is the correct fix, if it survives some more testing I'll get tabu updated on ctan.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}  
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\begin{varwidth}{0.91\linewidth}}l<{\end{varwidth}}}

\makeatletter
\def\tabu@verticalmeasure{\everypar{}%
\unless\ifnum\currentgrouptype=14 \let\tabu@currentgrouptype\currentgrouptype\fi
    \ifnum \tabu@currentgrouptype>12         % 14=semi-simple, 15=math shift group
        \setbox\tabu@box =\hbox\bgroup
            \let\tabu@verticalspacing \tabu@verticalsp@lcr
            \d@llarbegin                % after \hbox ...
    \else
        \edef\tabu@temp{\ifnum\tabu@currentgrouptype=5\vtop
                        \else\ifnum\tabu@currentgrouptype=12\vcenter
                        \else\vbox\fi\fi}%
        \setbox\tabu@box \hbox\bgroup$\tabu@temp \bgroup
            \let\tabu@verticalspacing \tabu@verticalsp@pmb
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}    
\begin{tabu}{Lcc}
$\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\2\\3    
\end{pmatrix}$& 2& 3\\
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I can test it right now, it works. Although the $ in the line  `\setbox\tabu@box \hbox\bgroup$\tabu@temp \bgroup` confuses my editor, because it sees it as a beginning of a formular.

Comment: @chris thanks I plan to push 2.10 to ctan now, so it should appear in texlive/miktex later in the week.

Comment: Thanks! However, I just found out, the above mentioned problem also occurs (exactly in the same way), when including a table (e.g tabular) in the tabu-environment and is not solved by this solution. (It also worked before the last update!)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle did you ever get a chance to upload 2.10 (latest version on CTAN appears to be 2.9 still), or did it not fix the issue?

Comment: @PeetWhittaker No people raised some issues on 2.10 as it is there and so it wasn't clear that that was the right change so it stalled and basically we are just using the github so people can record issues but maintenance will need to wait for a volunteer to maintain it, we simply don't have the bandwidth to pick up this package.

Answer (score 0):

The new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) is an alternative to the outdated `tabu` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\NewColumnType{L}{>{\begin{varwidth}{0.91\linewidth}}l<{\end{varwidth}}}

\begin{document}    

\begin{tblr}{Lcc}
$\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 2 \\ 3    
\end{pmatrix}$ & 2 & 3 \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]