# Using makecell in tabu: incompatibility with the packages tcolorbox and todonotes

Tags: tcolorbox, tabu, todonotes, makecell

I have a problem when using the package `tabu` with makecell and `tcolorbox` and `todonotes`. This is my minimal example code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{tabu,makecell}
\begin{document}
\noindent \begin{tabu} to \textwidth {@{}lXX}
normal line & A & B \\
line with makecell & \makecell[tl]{A\\C} & \makecell[tl]{B\\D\\E}
\end{tabu}
\todo{To Do: ...}
\end{document}
```

When I exclude the line with `\makecell`, everything works. Also when I exclude the packages `todo` and `tcolorbox` (and of course, the line with `\todo` command, but keep the line with `\makecell`), everything works.

The problem occurs when I include at least one of the packages `tcolorbox` or `todonotes`. Then I got the following error:

```
./test-tabu.tex:9: Improper \prevdepth.
\tabu@verticalspacing ...tempdimc \the \prevdepth 
                                              \@tempdima \dimexpr \ht 
\t...
l.9 \end{tabu}
```

Also the solution from [tabu: Error since update](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471000/tabu-error-since-update) didn't help.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Here is the first line of the log file:

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=pdflatex)

Comment: Add an issue here https://github.com/tabu-fixed/tabu and read the readme carefully.

Comment: Is your issue solved? How? Have you considered to **not use tabu any longer**?

Answer (score 1):

The new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) is an alternative to the outdated `tabu` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tblr}{
  width = \textwidth,
  colspec = {@{}lXX},
}
  normal line        & A                   & B \\
  line with makecell & \SetCell{t,l}{A\\C} & \SetCell{t,l}{B\\D\\E} \\
\end{tblr}
\todo{To Do: ...}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (compatible with `tcolorbox` and `todonotes`).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{NiceTabular}{@{}lXX}
  normal line        & A                   & B \\
  line with makecell & \Block[t,l]{}{A\\C} & \Block[t,l]{}{B\\D\\E} \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\bigskip
\todo{To Do: ...}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]