# LaTeX3 on Windows 11. What distribution to install

Tags: texlive, latex3, winedt

I'm about to get a new computer with Windows 11.
So far I have been using Win 8.1.
My question is whether I can install on it LaTeX3 as TeXLive distribution.
Is this LaTeX3 already stable and does it work with WinEdt 10.3 ?

Or, shall I just install the latest version of TeXLive ?
What is advisable to do this ?
Thank you for any hints.

Comment: there is no latex3, the expl3 code is incorporated in to latex2e and is part of all tex distributions. so you can get texlive or miktex whichever you are used to from your win8 version.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/661160/latex2e-vs-latex3/661167#661167